# Why did I lose with a flush in Omaha?

Tags: rules, omaha

I was holding an ace in my hand during an Omaha game. There were four clubs on the board.  Why did I lose this hand?

Comment: I closed your question because it lacks any proof of a research effort. Googling "poker Omaha" would give you plenty of results which contain exactly the answer you need. Please do a little research before asking.

Comment: This is a common question with new players to Omaha. It is a good question and deserves expert answers. Even after searching online the concept may still be hard to grasp. This is also a question that will have value for many future users of the site.

Comment: Don't know much about _Omaha_ but questions of 1.5 line tends to be more general than specific. Try to be more specific. All of our comments are larger than this question.

Comment: this question lacks the proper detail for a correct answer OP Please edit and include both hands and the board

Answer (score 13):

In Omaha Hold'em you have to use exactly two of the four cards from your hand and three on the board (since a poker hand is exactly five cards).

This means you can only have the flush when you have two cards of the same suit in your hand and there are at least three cards of that suit on the board.